# Django. Authentication backends

Tags: django, django-authentication, atlassian-crowd

I need to authenticate on some of atlassian services(wiki for example) and on AD(ActiveDirectory). The problem is I don't know how to make authentication in different back-ends so user input password and log-in only once and then backends authenticate user on different services. As I read in docs - django iterates through list of backends till user wouldn't be authenticate on django site. Or maybe i at all think in a wrong way?
How should I login on other services? I know about CROWD but guess it doesn't cover functionality for login on my MSSQL DB.

Comment: Is it unsolvable problem? Or just my question isn't correct? Should I provide some additional information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can customize authenticate mechanization by provide your own back-ends.
see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/